# Star Trek use of “Sabotage” as a theme

Tags: star-trek

As we have seen from the J.J. Abrams new generation of films he uses the Beastie Boys song “Sabotage”" in the original film and his the trailer for the newest film.  We will also note that Valeris in *Undiscovered Country* explains the etymology of “sabotage.” Is this a conscious reference to original movie series or just a happy coincidence?

Comment: In the new trailer, I believe it is a reference to the success of a certain other space movie.

Comment: Sabotage was also the theme used for the young James Kirk in the first J.J. Abrams Star Trek film.

Comment: Doesn't another BB song actually reference Star Trek, specifically Spock? Intergalactic?

Answer (score 6):

This answer may not be liked well because its simplicity.  But actually its just because J.J. Abrams is a huge Beastie Boys fan. That’s it. Simple. The is also known to put Beastie Boys easter eggs in his work.

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, look at Resistance fighter pilot named “[Ello Asty](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Star-Wars-Awesome-Tribute-Beastie-Boys-99607.html).” Ihe bottom of his helmet looks to say “Born to Ill” as in he doesn’t need a [“License to Ill.”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licensed_to_Ill) J.J. Abrams does this a lot with Beastie Boys references. He’s just a huge fan.

Answer (score 0):

J.J. Abrams does like references and throwbacks to the old films and series, but you also have to remember that sabotage is also a theme in the *Into Darkness* - Marcus sabotaging the warp core of the Enterprise, Scotty sabotaging the Vengeance - and in the (new original?) Star Trek, where Kirk sabotages the  *Kobayashi Maru* test. It may just be a hint of things to come.

Comment: That's a very interesting observation.  So for one J.J. Abrams is a known Beastie Boys fan?  Also The sabotage plot element in all those movies.  Between both your answers you summed up Abrahms' like for the BB, but is there any evidence for his inspiration from the TOS movies?